# Accessing the internet API using modules in python

Tags: python, import, request, response

what is the difference between the below two modules?

```
import urlib.request
import response
```

Here both modules are used to get the input from Internet API's. But what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in: `import urlib.request` you are gonna import method from module/library.

And in this case: `import response` you are gonna import the module itself.

In the first instance you would be able to use `request` method directly in your code, while in the second you have to do something like: `response.some_method`

Comment: I meant what is the difference in their functionality not the syntax

Comment: There is no difference in their functionality at all